# Django Admin filtering ForeignKey dropdown based on another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have 3 Models:

```
class FileType(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ManagedFile(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(FileType)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to=path_maker)

class Tag(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(FileType)
    m_file = models.ForeignKey(ManagedFile)

    def clean(self):
        if self.m_file is None:
            return
        if self.type != self.m_file.type:
            raise ValidationError("File type does not match Tag type")
```

When select an m_file for a tag, the m_files type MUST match the Tags type. This is all well and good, but the admin drop down for Tag.m_file shows files of all types, regardless of the Tag's type. This is Confusing to users.

There seem to me a number of ways to filter the drop down statically. So if I wanted to say that we will never let the user see Type.pk=1 in the dropdown, I can to that.  But there does not seem to be a way to filter on m_file.Type == Self.Type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to create your admin form classes dynamically. Something like this should work:

```
def tagform_factory(filetype):
    class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):
        m_file = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=ManagedFile.objects.filter(type=filetype)
        )
    return TagForm


class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj is not None and obj.type is not None:
            kwargs['form'] = tagform_factory(obj.type)
        return super(TagAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Note that the `get_form` method is responsible for building the form *class*, not the form *instance*. It is badly named, IMHO.

However, you still need to decide what to do for forms that are used to add new tags, rather than edit existing ones. In that case you do not yet have a type to which you can restrict the dropdown. Maybe there is actually a data modeling problem lurking here? Do you really need the `type` field on the `Tag` model? Maybe it should just be removed?

Comment: The project has actually moved beyond this, and Tags are no longer a thing. It WAS a data modeling problem. The way it worked did require Tags to have a type, but we realized that we actually didn't need Tags at all (Also, Tags were badly named and should have been called Slots or something)

But this was exactly the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding `formfield_for_foreignkey()` in the admin. I'm not 100% it does what you want it to do, but if not it should get you started:

```
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs['queryset'] = Tag.objects.filter(type=self.type)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, formfield_for_foreignkey does not get passed the object currently being edited? Several other admin functions get a obj argument for this.

Comment: I think you're right. Surely you can only filter based on the object in a change view, not when adding an object? If I understand your problem. In this case, you might be able to do override `change_view()`