# How to I restrict Django admin select options when using in an admin.TabularInline?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm tearing hair out here trying to do something that feels like it should be simple, but I can't work out how to do this in Django.

I have three models.

```
class Survey()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Reference()
  field = models.ForeignKey(Survey)

class SurveyItem()
  field = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
  reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to be able to show these on a single form, so when a user has created a survey and added some references for their survey, they are then able to choose add SurveyItems with that Reference in the inline part of the form.

```
class SurveyInfoItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SurveyInfoItem
    extra = 3

class ReferenceItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Reference
    extra = 2

class StaticSurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [ReferenceItemInline, SurveyItemInline]
```

I currently have this form created, and it's clunky, but people can make submissions successfully with it.

However, but I can't see a way to scope an inline form, so that when users are creating *SurveyInfoItems* on a *Survey* with the SurveyInfoItemInline widget, they only choose from *References* that were added previously to this survey, rather than showing all the *References* in the table on an app.

I've looked through stackoverflow, and found a few similar questions:

- [Django Admin filtering ForeignKey dropdown based on another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664518/django-admin-filtering-foreignkey-dropdown-based-on-another-field/31014181#31014181)
- [Limit the queryset of entries displayed for a django admin Inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703652/limit-the-queryset-of-entries-displayed-for-a-django-admin-inline?rq=1)

But pretty much everything I've tried has failed to affect how many References are available to choose from.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey ? (also works for Inlines)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I'd say your best bet here is to write a small JavaScript function for your admin page to hide unwanted SurveyItem choices based on currently selected References. Afterwards, you can do validation/cleanup in your admin save() method.

If you want to do everything server-side, the user experience will have to take at least two requests (page loads): the first one to set the survey references, and the next one to filter survey items using those references. Even then, the options still won't adjust in real-time when the user is adding/removing survey references on the page. It's a good question nevertheless--there isn't an obvious way to get the parent model data in the tabularInline (e.g. [Prepopulating inlines based on the parent model in the Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883296/prepopulating-inlines-based-on-the-parent-model-in-the-django-admin) )--but I think overall it might be the least headache approaching this with JS.