# Django , linking three models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a question. I have a Bb model that includes the rubric and sub_rubric parameters. There are also Rubric and Sub_rubric models, one-to-many related. Question: how to link rubric and sub_rubric to each other in the Bb model, so that when a new instance of the Bb model is created, when the rubric changes, the subrubruc list changes too.

```
Code: 
class Rubric(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)

   
class Sub_Rubric(models.Model):
    rubric = models.ForeignKey(Rubric, null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True,  unique = True)
class Bb(models.Model):
   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, )
    rubric = models.ForeignKey(Rubric, null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name='name')
    sub_rubric = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Rubric, null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/foreign-keys-django-tutorial/)
[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)
[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#relationships)
These may help

Answer (score 0):

In Bb you should only define a foreign key to sub_rubric. You can always get to Rubric via Sub_rubric.

Comment: If I do this, there is a very long sub_rubric list. Is it possible to make linked lists in django?

Comment: I cant reply as it seems I do not entirely understand your problem. Maybe you add some more explanation.

Comment: In the admin panel, when I select one rubric from the list (for example, transport), the second list shows me all the sub_rubrics of all rubric (for example, when selecting rubric "transport", sub_rubric displays except "motorcycles , cars", also displays "studio apartment, house," and others). How to get around it? I hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: ok - got it. maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664518/django-admin-filtering-foreignkey-dropdown-based-on-another-field

Comment: here is an example outside of admin: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html